# Mover celdas de tabla HTML con el mouse

Tags: html

existe la posibilidad de mover las celdas de una tabla HTML con el mouse ?

La intención es permitir a una tabla **HTML** cambiar el tamaño de las **filas y columnas** arrastrando y soltando con el mouse

Si es así, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo ?

Gracias

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674548/how-to-make-html-table-columns-resizable) del SO en inglés tienen una posible solución

Comment: Por favor leer [ask]. Aquí no hacemos software a medida. ¿Qué has intentado o investigado? Sin JS, lo único que te queda es CSS mediante algún atributo como `resize`. ¿Cómo podrías hacerlo? Pues como todos, escribiendo y probando. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Si, si es posible siempre y cuando utilices javascript, pues este va a encargarse de interactuar con el **front-end** una vez carguen los elementos del **DOM**

Te dejo un ejemplo de [como estirar las columnas empleando JS](https://webdevtrick.com/resizable-table-columns/)

```js
const min = 150;
// The max (fr) values for grid-template-columns
const columnTypeToRatioMap = {
  numeric: 1,
  'text-short': 1.67,
  'text-long': 3.33 };


const table = document.querySelector('table');

                                          
const columns = [];
let headerBeingResized;

// The next three functions are mouse event callbacks

// Where the magic happens. I.e. when they're actually resizing
const onMouseMove = e => requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  console.log('onMouseMove');

  // Calculate the desired width
  horizontalScrollOffset = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  const width = horizontalScrollOffset + e.clientX - headerBeingResized.offsetLeft;

  // Update the column object with the new size value
  const column = columns.find(({ header }) => header === headerBeingResized);
  column.size = Math.max(min, width) + 'px'; // Enforce our minimum

  // For the other headers which don't have a set width, fix it to their computed width
  columns.forEach(column => {
    if (column.size.startsWith('minmax')) {// isn't fixed yet (it would be a pixel value otherwise)
      column.size = parseInt(column.header.clientWidth, 10) + 'px';
    }
  });

  /* 
        Update the column sizes
        Reminder: grid-template-columns sets the width for all columns in one value
      */
  table.style.gridTemplateColumns = columns.
  map(({ header, size }) => size).
  join(' ');
});

// Clean up event listeners, classes, etc.
const onMouseUp = () => {
  console.log('onMouseUp');

  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
  headerBeingResized.classList.remove('header--being-resized');
  headerBeingResized = null;
};

// Get ready, they're about to resize
const initResize = ({ target }) => {
  console.log('initResize');

  headerBeingResized = target.parentNode;
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
  headerBeingResized.classList.add('header--being-resized');
};

// Let's populate that columns array and add listeners to the resize handles
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(header => {
  const max = columnTypeToRatioMap[header.dataset.type] + 'fr';
  columns.push({
    header,
    // The initial size value for grid-template-columns:
    size: `minmax(${min}px, ${max})` });

  header.querySelector('.resize-handle').addEventListener('mousedown', initResize);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

table {
  min-width: 100vw;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  display: grid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  grid-template-columns: 
    minmax(150px, 1fr)
    minmax(150px, 1.67fr)
    minmax(150px, 1.67fr)
    minmax(150px, 1.67fr)
    minmax(150px, 3.33fr)
    minmax(150px, 1.67fr)
    minmax(150px, 3.33fr)
    minmax(150px, 1.67fr);
}

thead,
tbody,
tr {
  display: contents;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #5cb85c;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

th:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

.resize-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 3px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.resize-handle:hover,
.header--being-resized .resize-handle {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

th:hover .resize-handle {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

td {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #808080;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #f8f6ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Resizable Table Columns | Webdevtrick.com</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-type="numeric">ID <span class="resize-handle"></span></th>
      <th data-type="text-short">First name <span class="resize-handle"></span></th>
      <th data-type="text-short">Last name <span class="resize-handle"></span></th>
      <th data-type="text-short">Email <span class="resize-handle"></span></th>
      <th data-type="text-long">Street <span class="resize-handle"></span></th>
      <th data-type="text-short">Country <span class="resize-handle"></span></th>
      <th data-type="text-long">Pincode <span class="resize-handle"></span></th>
      <th data-type="text-short">IBAN <span class="resize-handle"></span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>000001</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>usermail@gmail.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>United State</td>
      <td>21520</td>
      <td>XYZ123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>000002</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>usermail@gmail.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>United State</td>
      <td>21520</td>
      <td>XYZ123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>000003</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>usermail@gmail.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>United State</td>
      <td>21520</td>
      <td>XYZ123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>000004</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>usermail@gmail.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>United State</td>
      <td>21520</td>
      <td>XYZ123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>000005</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>usermail@gmail.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>United State</td>
      <td>21520</td>
      <td>XYZ123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>000006</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>usermail@gmail.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>United State</td>
      <td>21520</td>
      <td>XYZ123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>000007</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>usermail@gmail.com</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>United State</td>
      <td>21520</td>
      <td>XYZ123</td>
    </tr>



  </tbody>
</table>

<script  src="function.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Quizá probando búsquedas en ingles te facilite un poco mas lo que buscas, prueba con ***"Resize table rows drag and drop javascript"***. Puedes ver este otro ejemplo: [Ejemplo](https://codingdeekshi.com/javascript-project-to-resize-html5/)

Comment: Muchas gracias lo intentare

Comment: Por favor, evita responder este tipo de preguntas tan mal formuladas ya que terminan cerradas y tu aporte se pierde. Saludos

Comment: El título reza "sin javascript" pero ahora parece que le da igual :-)

Comment: es que ya veo que no es posible hacerlo sin JavaScript, por lo que tengo pensado editar la pregunta. Gracias